# Prime characteristic $p$ and Power series ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R=K[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$ the power series ring over a field $K$ of prime characteristic $p$. If we take $K$ if $F$-finite, I know show that  $R^{1/p}$ is a free $R$-module. If $K$ not is $F$-finite, is $R^{1/p}$ a free $R$-module?

Notation. $R^{1/p}$ is the set of $p$-
th roots of elements of $R$ ,i.e, $R^{1/p}=\{r^{1/p} \mid r \in R\}$. Its $R$-module structure is given by $s \cdot r^{1/p}=(s^pr)^{1/p}$.

Comment: You should probably define $R^{1/p}$ here too. I can't guess what the notation is, and if [Thomas Andrews doesn't recognize it either](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4650898/power-series-ring-in-prime-characteristic#comment9820244_4650898) then we know for sure it is obscure.

Comment: Why don't you try writing out a proof in the $F$-finite case?

Comment: The $F$-Finito case is simple and very common, my question is when it is not $F$-infinite.